can you convert standard Web API request to NextApiRequest object?
I am in a situation where, I am using turborepo and there is already application with pages router, but the new application I am trying to add is using app router.
First of let me know if this is a good thing or not as I have plan to migrate other app with pages router to app router gradually since it's really big.
both of this apps depends on single api package, and I have defined one handler method for Google Authentication like this.
// packages/api/src/auth/index.ts

export const handleGoogleAuth = (
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse,
  redirectUrl: string,
) => {
  if (req.method === "GET") {
    const { auth } = req.query;

    if (auth?.[0] === "google" && auth?.[1] === "auth") {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        passport.authenticate("google", {
          scope: ["profile", "email"],
          session: false,
        })(req, res, (error: any) => {
          if (error) reject(error);
          else resolve(error);
        });
      });
    }

    if (auth?.[0] === "google" && auth?.[1] === "callback") {
      return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
        passport.authenticate(
          "google",
          { session: false },
          (err: any, user: any) => {
            if (err) {
              res.redirect(`${redirectUrl}?error=AuthenticationFailed`);
              return resolve();
            }
            if (!user) {
              res.redirect(`${redirectUrl}?error=UserNotFound`);
              return resolve();
            }
            sendAuthCookies(res, user);
            res.redirect(redirectUrl);
            resolve();
          },
        )(req, res, (error: any) => {
          if (error) reject(error);
          else resolve(error);
        });
      });
    }
  }

  res.status(404).json({ message: "Not found" });
};

I am using this method in my pages router app like this, which works perfect.
// apps/pages-router-app/api/auth/[...auth].ts

import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";

import { handleGoogleAuth } from "@monorepo/api";

import { env } from "~/env";

export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse,
) {
  try {
    await handleGoogleAuth(req, res, env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PAGES_ROUTER_HOSTED_URL);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Authentication error:", error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal Server Error" });
  }
}

When I try to do the same in app router it gives error like query does not exist and in catch block .status does not exist on res. I was doing some research about if there is a built in wrapper exist to convert normal Request to NextApiRequest object but couldn't found anything online, also there is not much discussion going on about this.
// apps/app-router-app/api/auth/[...auth]/route.ts

import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import { env } from "@/app/env";

import { handleGoogleAuth } from "@monorepo/api";

// Giving type like this don't work since it's still sending normal request object in app router I guess
export async function GET(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  try {
    await handleGoogleAuth(req, res, env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_ROUTER_HOSTED_URL);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Authentication error:", error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal Server Error" });
  }
}

If there is no way let me know what would you do in this case? Giving that in future you want to move to app router.
